# Cloudformation - Are mappings from parent stack passed to Child?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have the following structure (pretty much boilerplate). My question her is, are Mappings that I define in the ParentStack available in the ChildSTacks or would I need to duplicate them? I KNOW I can pass in Parameters to the ChildStack but was wondering if the Mappngs are implicitely passed to ChildStacks so I dont have to duplicaet them in each Child Stack?

```
ParentStack (Containing Mappings, Parameters)
   ChildStack1
   ChildStack2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they aren't.

You can consider nested stacks as standalone stacks but their creation/update/deletion is orchestrated by the parent stack.

This limitation is usually easy to workaround by having the parent stack execute the `FindInMap` operation when passing down the parameters to the child stack.